# How to search on many fields of a single MySQL table without using many OR conditions?

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns

I'm currently working on a php page that search over a table some data. The problem is that the searched string can be in "field1", "field2", "field3" or "field4".

How to do this SQL query without using 4 OR conditions ?

Here is the query I do have at this very moment.

`SELECT a_field FROM my_table WHERE LOWER(field1) = 'searched_string' OR LOWER(field2) = 'searched_string' OR LOWER(field3) = 'searched_string' OR LOWER(field4) = 'searched_string'`

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think this is an problem? You should build your query dynamically, so you don't need to care about number of "OR" in the query.

Comment: The problem is that I can't know before on which field to apply the search. That's why I have to search over all fields.

Comment: If you have to search over all fields, so using OR is the right way. I still can't see the problem. I hope you don't change your query manually? You must have some array of fields to be searched, and build the query dynamically.

Comment: The problem is that type of query takes a while (for our needs) to execute on 100 hundreds of rows and I hoped to find a better/smarter way to handle this need.

Comment: There is no other way to do this.

Comment: The fact that this is even a problem is a huge red flag of a poor database design.  The fact that you are using a column name as the argument to a function in the where clause also means that your queries will always perform badly, because indexes will be completely ignored, assuming you have them. (e.g. `LOWER(col1)`)

Comment: If `col1` is has a default collation or other collation ending in "_ci", you don't need the `LOWER()`.  This is because the collation is 'case insensitive'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use match for this. But first you need to create your indexes.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(field_1, field_2) AGAINST ('keyword or expression');
```

You can find details in documentation.

Innodb full text search support comes after version 5.6

[Mysql Full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seems to works in our case.

Comment: @user2193135 - Why doesn't it work? If you want an answer you need to be more specific.

Comment: I understand. Currently using an InnoDB database on MySQL 5.6, but after changed table definition using "ALTER TABLE", I still get "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list" from MySQL server.

Comment: Did you create fulltext index for your columns?

Comment: Yes. I've made a fulltext index with 4 fields from initial message.

Comment: I think this is a wrong solution for you. Full-text search uses threshold and min word length for searching. You better read about this more carefully before you continue with it...